# Multiple placemarks display on google map using URL

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-urls

i am currently displaying a single Placemark on google map using q= parameter:
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=lat long

Now i want to display multiple points/Placemark, i couldn't find a way other then using dir interface:
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/lat1 long1/lat2 long2....
But this display a route and not points - and the route doesn't always represent the real route as it depends on roads...

Is there a way to display multiple point, lines, placemarks using google maps API through URL ?

Comment: [Maps Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3059044/2648551

Comment: You can process the query string on your Google Maps Javascript API v3 page to add markers and polylines to the map.

Comment: Using Java script doesn't feet my application, I want to produce this through URL parmeters - can I use the JavaScript through URL without adding any files?

Answer (score 3):

I am able to get two simple points on a map using "/ /" between the addresses. For instance, the following URL:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/5+St+Marks+Pl,+New+York,+NY+10003/+/18+W+8th+St,+New+York,+NY+10011

Produces the following result, showing two points:

[image: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/5+St+Marks+Pl,+New+York,+NY+10003/+/18+W+8th+St,+New+York,+NY+10011]